# How do I avoid repetition when concatenating to one of three strings?

Tags: javascript

I have the following ugly pattern:

```js
// defined once
const articleComponents = {
    header: "",
    sections: [], // {title: string, content: string}[]
    footer: ""
};

// ...

function appendSuffix(suffix)
{
    if (/* target header */) {
        if (!articleComponents.header.endsWith(" ")) {
            articleComponents.header += " ";
        }
        articleComponents.header += suffix;
    }
    else if (/* target body */) {
        if (!articleComponents.sections[articleComponents.sections.length - 1].content.endsWith(" ")) {
            articleComponents.sections[articleComponents.sections.length - 1].content += " ";
        }
        articleComponents.sections[articleComponents.sections.length - 1].content += suffix;
    }
    else if (/* target footer */) {
        if (!articleComponents.footer.endsWith(" ")) {
            articleComponents.footer += " ";
        }
        articleComponents.footer += suffix;
    }
}
```

This is obviously redundant but due to the nature of the `+=` operator for strings, and strings being immutable, it's hard to simplify this.

#### Goals

- Ideally, in each if-statement, the `articleComponents.xyz`/`articleComponents.sections[articleComponents.sections.length - 1].content` expression should appear *exactly once*.
- `articleComponents` should not be modified; I rely on its format

  - additional helper objects inside `appendSuffix` are okay

#### C++ Counterpart

For clarity, this is how I could write it in C++ (simplified):

```cpp
void appendSuffix(string_view suffix) {
    string &target = /* target header */ ? articleComponents.header
                   : /* target body */   ? articleComponents.back().content
                   : /* target footer */ ? articleComponents.footer
                   : throw ...;

    if (target.back() != ' ') {
        target += ' ';
    }
    target += suffix;
}
```

It would be great if I could have something along those lines in JS.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've over-simplified the original a bit too much. This wouldn't work with the edited version.

Comment: Just abstract out “get current value” and “set new value”, then the condition is selecting whichever implementation of that abstraction is relevant.

Comment: @jonrsharpe then I would be calling "get value" and "set value", both with `articleComponents.sections[articleComponents.sections.length - 1].content` . This is still redundant, so it doesn't solve my problem. Plus I'd still be doing this in every if-statement presumably.

Comment: You can still do it with object and property, it’s just that in your more complex case the object isn’t always articleComponents itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one here?

```js
const articleComponents = {
  header: ' ',
  sections: [{
      title: 's1.title',
      content: 's1.content',
    },
    {
      title: 's2.title',
      content: 's2.content',
    },
    {
      title: 's3.title',
      content: 's3.content',
    }
  ],
  footer: ''
};

// This could be an enum in TS
const Target = {
  HEADER: 'HEADER',
  BODY: 'BODY',
  FOOTER: 'FOOTER'
};

function processString(str, suffix) {
  return !str.endsWith(' ') ? `${str} ${suffix}` : `${str}${suffix}`;
}

function processSections(sections, suffix) {
  const lastIndex = sections.length - 1;
  sections[lastIndex].content = processString(sections[lastIndex].content, suffix);
}

function appendSuffix(suffix, target) {
  switch (target) {
    case Target.HEADER:
      articleComponents.header = processString(articleComponents.header, suffix);
      break;
    case Target.FOOTER:
      articleComponents.footer = processString(articleComponents.footer, suffix);
      break;
    case Target.BODY:
      processSections(articleComponents.sections, suffix);
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error(`Invalid target ${target}!`);
  }
}

appendSuffix('SUFFIX', Target.HEADER);
appendSuffix('SUFFIX', Target.BODY);
appendSuffix('SUFFIX', Target.FOOTER);

console.log(articleComponents);
```

Comment: The goal is to modify the contents of `articleComponents`. If I'm reading this code correctly, this doesn't write back to the object.

Comment: @JanSchultke Usually, you don't modify the source directly, but instead, you create a copy. If this is a requirement we can change it. Edit: I slightly modified the code so it writes the the object directly.

Comment: That looks better, but `processSections` looks really fishy to me. Why would you `map` just to modify a single element?

Comment: @JanSchultke It does not really matter. It is considered an antipattern to directly modify the source. Think of side effects or asynchronous stuff ... if you reference your articleComponents somewhere else in the code it might break if you rely on certain conditions - this is also why there are things like DTOs and ImmutableCollections. I've edited the code again. It will update the object in memory now.